# How can I assign forEach to variable? Its possible?

Tags: javascript, variables, foreach, scope

Hello everyone:) I'm trying to write rock, paper, scissors game but I have a little problem. Is there any option to assign **let playerChoice = buttons.forEach...** to any variable as I did in this code? Unfortunately, it doesn't work like this. I attached my code below.

Thanks for any tips!

```
let choiceOptions = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"];
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');


let computerChoice = () => choiceOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceOptions.length)];

let playerChoice = buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        return button.id.toUpperCase();
    });
});

console.log(playerChoice) //does not work
```

Comment: No it is not possible. The click is asynchronous. You ordered a pizza and you are trying to eat it as soon as you put in the order. You are going to have to call a function when they click. `button.addEventListener('click', () => { theyClicked(button.id.toUpperCase()) });` and in that function do what you need to do.

Comment: You can't have, right now, some value that is generated by the user clicking on something sometime in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help.

Comment: JS is event based; here's how to approach this: https://jsfiddle.net/by2f4cn9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `forEach` to do what you want here.

First of all, `forEach` doesn't return anything ever, but second of all, you're returning the `button.id.toUpperCase()` later, when the user actually clicks the button.  Returning from an event handler won't assign the value anywhere useful.

Instead you should add the `playerChoice` variable in a shared outer scope, and assign to it upon the event.

```
let playerChoice;
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        playerChoice = button.id.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

In this way, `playerChoice` will be updated when the user clicks a button.

However, this probably won't actually help you, because your code won't know that the variable has been updated.  So instead, let's create a callback that your event handler can call.

```
let playerChoice;
let setPlayerChoice = (choice) => {
  playerChoice = choice;
  // we can use the value of playerChoice now, 
  // because this callback is being triggered 
  // by the user clicking the button.
  console.log(playerChoice); 
}
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        setPlayerChoice(button.id.toUpperCase());
    });
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, now I can move on with code ;)

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  Please go ahead and mark this answer as correct so that other users may find it.